# ./configure set Makefile name

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu, configure

if I run `./configure`, it automatically creates a Makefile called "Makefile". However, in the folder where i invoke `./configure`, there is already a Makefile (it is my "main"-Makefile). Is it somehow possible, to tell `./configure` that it should create the Makefile with a different name (e.q Makefile.1)?

I know, that I could move my "main"-Makefile to a different folder, but I want to avoid that, if it's possible.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So what do you want to do with the Makefile created by `./configure`? `include` it into your own?

Answer (score 3):

Rename your `Makefile.in` to `Makefile.1.in` and list

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
  Makefile.1
  ... other stuff ...
])
```

in your `configure.ac` (and run `autoreconf`). If you're using automake, rename your `Makefile.am` to `Makefile.1.am` instead of renaming the generated `Makefile.in`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't want to move your main Makefile, you still could rename it into "GNUmakefile", which takes precedence over "Makefile".

That is, invoking `make` in the project directory will execute the GNUmakefile, which in turn would probably hook into a generated one through `make -f Makefile`.